# Hadoop - Mapreduce job fails to run in Windows (Cygwin)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed cygwin in windows, and configured the hadoop0.20.0 set up on it, i could able to run the word count project in eclipse successfully, but when i run the wordcount in hadoop-*.*.*-example.jar,it throws the following error

```
3/06/28 07:32:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/06/28 07:32:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306280622_0002
13/06/28 07:32:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/28 07:32:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :  attempt_201306280622_0002_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201306280622_0002_m_000002_0:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: //job.jar: invalid mode: `jar'
Try `//job.jar --help' for more information.

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java: 286)
```

what would be the problem, plz assit

Comment: what is you command to run jar?

Comment: @twid, bin/hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.0-examples.jar wordcount /user/input /user/output

Answer (score 0):

Your commands looks fine to me. try giving input path with file name. I hope that will solve your problem.

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.0-examples.jar wordcount /user/input/input_file.txt /user/output
```

Comment: but its not correct view right, because if we need process a bunch of file means, mentioning the each filename is big job.